# How to model MIMO channel matrix for numerical results

Tags: wireless, wifi, beamforming

I am willing to include the channel matrix in my analytical model (which only includes pathloss and antenna gains). But from what I have seen, channel matrix can't be used to produce numerical results in an analytical model because it relies and should be based on real device tests.

Is my way of thinking wrong in this problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question – the thing is called **channel** matrix. It describes the **channel**, not just your device.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, I want to model this channel in order to produce analytical results, specifically, I want to calculate the capacity when using MIMO

Comment: well, then model it? The MIMO channel isn't any different than any other random channel there.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the answer, but my problem is how to get a channel matrix in order to produce numerical results